# Cars manufacturers or car manufacturers?

Tags: grammatical-number

While referring to an attribute of a group of objects, should the attribute alone be pluralized or should the objects be pluralized as well? Is there a rule that can be used to identify which word(s) have to be pluralized?

Which is the correct phrase that has to be used in the following scenarios?

Eg 1: If I have a list of companies that make cars, should it say "These are the car manufacturers" or "There are the cars manufacturers"?

Eg 2: Student names v/s students names. (list of students)

Eg 3: Student count v/s students count. (a single number with the number of students in the list)

Comment: I asked the same question few days ago. Today I posted my own answer, see it here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/229726

Answer (score 2):

For each of your three scenarios, the first example is correct.

Car manufacturers

Student names

Student count

Comment: I agree about the others, but I would say _list of students' names_  (because each one has an individual name).

Comment: Kate, agree with that. Was just responding to the first part “Student names v/s students names”